# Why not transfer the signal back?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

During the final battle, the plan is to take out a beacon that allows the fleet to navigate off world.  The plan changes when a different source is chosen as the beacon, and the assault redirects to it.

After the disabling of the new beacon, or even as the Resistance is redirecting, why not just setup the original beacon as the source again?

Comment: Because it was essentially unguarded?

Comment: @Valorum but they were needing to send in a ground operation to disable it. Once they are deployed in a different location, it would take a while to pack back up and move.  Alternatively, something resembling a baseball runner stuck between plates as they throw the ball back and forth.

Comment: Transferring it took a short while, during which time the Destroyers were effectively defenceless. Transferring it back would have much the same effect and you're now facing a fleet which can deploy ground troops by the thousands

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of reasons.

1. The deck officer seemed to believe that there was something to fix on the ship itself. He says something to the effect of "they're working on it"
2. Just as the Battle of Endor, chaos had erupted within the fleet. Even if they had transferred the signal back, it wasn't clear any ships were capable of leaving the system as they were. After all, many were still fighting off the armada of ships.

Comment: And the weakness to blow them up had been found.........